# Regarding implementation of kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am not sure if this is the right stack exchange but please say so if it isn't and I will try to post my question in the relevant place.

My questions is regarding the implementation of a discrete time Kalman filter assuming the time update occurs much more often than measurement update. I'll be specifically looking at the covariance propagation and Kalman gain equations.

Given a D.T. KF with the following state space model:
$$
\hat{x}_{k+1} = F \hat{x}_k + G \omega_k
$$
$$
\hat{y}_k = C \hat{x}_k + \upsilon_k
$$
and assuming $\hat{x}^-(0)$ and $P^-(0)$ are known as well as the process and measurement noise intensities (Q and R respectively) the relevant equations are:

Gain update:
$$
K = P^-C^T (CP^- C^T + R)^{-1}
$$
Measurement update
$$
P^- = F P^+ F^T + Q
$$
Time Update:
$$
P^+ = (I-KC)P^-
$$

The difficulty I am having is with respect to implementation and how to properly initialize. A pseudo code example of what I think should be done is the following:

```
% Pp = P-
% Pu = P+
Pp = P0;                                       % Initializing P-
for i=1:N                                      % N = number of measurement updates
    for j=1:m                                  % m = number of time updates in one measurement update
        Pp = F*Pu*F' + Qd;                     % covariance prop
        K = [K, Pp*C'*(R + C*Pp*C')^(-1)];     % update gain
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    end
    Pu = (eye(nx) - K(:,cnt)*C)*Pp;            % measurement update
    cnt = cnt + 1;
end
```

But this has the problem that the first iteration `Pp` cannot compute because there has yet to be a measurement update. This is easily solved by forcing a measurement update before any time updates. Maybe it's just me but it seems kind of incorrect to NEED a measurement update before any time updates.

Comment: You are talking about a discrete time system but your state equation seems to indicated a continuous time system. I assume the dot should the state at the next time step instead of a derivative? And why are you updating the process noise covariance, I assume it should be the error covariance ($P$) instead?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry for the silly mistakes, was looking at a summary of the equations from a book and didn't realize their notation was slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong for a number of reasons. First you do not want to compute `m` times the same value of `Pp`:

```
Pp = F*Pu*F' + Qd; %this will be the same value computed over and over
```

since `F`,`Pu` and `Q_d` don't change. I assume you meant to write

```
Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd;
```

Let's rewrite your outer loop body as:

```
for j=1:m                
        Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd;                     
        K = [K, Pp*C'*(R + C*Pp*C')^(-1)];     
        cnt = cnt + 1; 
end
```

Your issue is now almost fixed. Let's set set `m=1` as the issue will hold regardless of `m`:

```
Pp = P0
for i=1:N 
   Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd;                     
   K = [K, Pp*C'*(R + C*Pp*C')^(-1)];
   Pu = (eye(nx) - K(:,cnt)*C)*Pp;  
   cnt = cnt + 1   
end
```

the code will run correctly for the first loop, but for `i=2` step 
`Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd;` will be wrong (correctness of value computed - it will still run). We fix this with the following

```
Pu = P0
for i=1:N 
   Pp=Pu
   Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd;                     
   K = [K, Pp*C'*(R + C*Pp*C')^(-1)];
   Pu = (eye(nx) - K(:,cnt)*C)*Pp;
   cnt = cnt + 1     
end
```

Now your Kalman filter matches the classic definition. Note that `Pp` is usually defined as the predict covariance and `Pu` update covariance. For initializing the Kalman filter `Pu` is defined (and not Pp like you did). Putting it all together:

```
Pu = P0
for i=1:N 
   Pp = Pu
   for j=1:m
       Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd;                     
       K = [K, Pp*C'*(R + C*Pp*C')^(-1)];
       Pu = (eye(nx) - K(:,cnt)*C)*Pp;    ]
       cnt = cnt + 1 
    end
    Pu = (eye(nx) - K(:,cnt)*C)*Pp;
    cnt = cnt + 1
end
```

Comment: Regarding your first comment I do tho, because continuing time updates while waiting for measurement can be necessary depending on the use case. Secondly Pp = F*Pp*F' + Qd; is just not the right equation for the time update step. Finally you say Pu, $P^+$, is the one initialized; from what I've seen in text books I can't agree with that. Given I have not exhaustively searched through all KF textbooks, but the ones I have seen initialize $P^-$.

Comment: I am not arguing against your use of propagating the model while waiting for the measurement - it is just that your code was _wrong_ as it computed the same value over and over again (`Pp = F*Pu*F' + Qd;`). "just not the right equation for the time update step. " - you're confusing correctness of a mathematical formula for how math gets translated to code.  `Pu` is indeed the one initialized (the one  required in the first 'measurement' update) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

Comment: $P_{0|0}$ (`Pu` or $P^{+}$) is initialized in order to be used in the predict phase to compute $P_{1|0}$ (`Pp` or $P^{-}$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Details

Comment: I see what you mean regarding the calculation of Pp in the time update, yes the implementation is definitely not 1:1 with the math. There should probably have been some kind of carry over between successive time updates.

Comment: With regards to initialization I am not quite sure what to make of it. The wikipedia article has an example on "hybrid KF" in which they initialize P- and x-. And if you look at textbooks like "Aided Navigation: GPS with High Rate Sensors" or "Linear Systems Control: Deterministic and Stochastic Methods" they both describe initializing as setting x- and P- to x(0) and P(0). Of course textbooks are not necessarily 100% correct but I do not see much support for initializing x+ and P+, if you have some other source I would love to see it.